# Can javascript call web.py template session variable?

Tags: python, web.py

I have saved the validate code in session variable,and I use the web.py template to pass the session to the html page with $context.How can I compare it with user input code by javascript or transfer it to javascript code for comparing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not do that, you can only rennder the javascript(a part of html) use the session varibale, but after it is rendered, the html is fixed! So you can not use the session variable of tempalte context.

May you can try to generate a variable in the rendered html by using your template session variable.

e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var username = "$context.username";
</script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var session = {
        foo: "$context.foo",
        bar: "$context.bar",
        ...
    };
</script>
```

In your application code:

```
render = web.temlate.render('templaters', global={'context': session})
```

Comment: Many thanks.But when I tried alert the $context.validate_code in javascript,nothing appeared.And when I put the $context.validate_code in html code text control,I get the exactly value.Do u know why it happened?

Comment: Could you please provide your template file? :)

Comment: aha,I should leave out the double quotation marks.Now it works,but still exists some thing error.Not very important and I will solve it.Many thanks to you.

Comment: @Sedgwickz  sorry I forgot the `"`, if no `"`, the render result is just a symbol, and js will view it as a variable undefined. So alert nothing, But in html the symbol is just the string. :), And you can accept the anwser.